# Can I detect if a function was called with the error control operator (@)?

Tags: php, error-handling

I have custom error handler that is supposed to stop the execution of the application when an uncaught exception is thrown or some error/warning/notice is generated, display a nice error message, then email the developer about it.

Everything works well except that I can't find a way to ignore warnings that were generated by a function that was called with `@` (`ftp_login`)

`debug_backtrace()` shows the function name, but not `@`. Is there a way to detect it, or do I have to hard code the function name into the error handler?

Comment: I think XDebug will show you if there was an error that was suppressed by `@`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From PHP Manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

> PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When
> prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be
> generated by that expression will be ignored.
>
> If you have set a custom error handler function with
> set_error_handler() then it will still get called, but this custom
> error handler can (and should) call error_reporting() which will
> return 0 when the call that triggered the error was preceded by an @.

Just use "error_reporting() === 0" in your error handler to know where a function is preceded by a @

Comment: +1, but the docs seem to be wrong on this. `error_reporting()` returns the current error reporting level, that has nothing to do with the `$errno` being `0`, which is what you *should* check.

Comment: Well, it seems to work. It does return 0 inside the error handler, even if the error_reporting directive is set to -1 :)

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think of if you want to include it in an email is to capture the line from the file.  Assuming your error handler function has the signature:

```
bool handler(int $errno, string $errstr [,string $errfile [,int $errline [,array $errcontext]]])
```

Try:

```
$code = file($errfile)[$errline];
```

You can then include this text or `strpos` for an `@` and decide from there.